# Variable not used, when using a named return type

Tags: go, iterator, closures

Why can I do the following to define an iterator in Go:

```
func f() func() int {
    i := 1
    return func() int {
        i++
        return i
    }
}
```

but this will result in a variable not used error (`i` is not used)?

```
func f() func() int {
    i := 1
    return func() (i int) {
        i++
        return
    }
}
```

main function:

```
func main() {
    iter := f()
    fmt.Println(iter())
    fmt.Println(iter())
    fmt.Println(iter())
    fmt.Println(iter())
}
```

To me both versions do exactly the same: They use `f` as an iterator. `f` makes use of closures (more specifically `i`). The first version explicitly returns an incremented `i` and the second implicitly, by referring to it via a named return type.

To me both versions are the same, so why do I get an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case, the return value `(i int)` shadows the outer declaration `i := 1`.  So it's this first `i` that is unused. This means the second example isn't a closure at all.

From a scoping standpoint, your second example is the same as:

```
func f() func() int {
    i := 1
    return func(i int) int {
        i++
        return
    }
}
```

In this case, it should be clear that the inner `i` is distinct, and shadows the outer one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that. Could you please point out why a named return value is the same as a named argument? Do you have a link where I could read about that?

Comment: @User12547645 [Effective Go: Named result parameters](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results)

Comment: @User12547645: "The result parameters act as ordinary local variables and the function may assign values to them as necessary." As always, read the The Go Programming Language Specification: https://golang.org/ref/spec.

Comment: Thank you @icza. So if I use a named return parameter, this parameter is initialized as a zero value (0 for ints). This is why it is like a new parameter. Thank you.